# How to specify TimeZone in date formatting to get local time

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, python-3.x, datetime

I'm trying to compare two date values:

1) `Jun 23, 2016 10:36:31 EET`

2) `Thu, 23 Jun 2016 07:36:31 GMT`

To do this I need to convert second date to same date format as first one, so I use following code:

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.strptime("Thu, 23 Jun 2016 07:36:31 GMT", "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
    .strftime('%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

and get following output:

```
Jun 23, 2016 07:36:31
```

This is still `GMT` time (also time zone value not specified)

How should I update my `strftime` argument to get `Jun 23, 2016 10:36:31 EET` as output?

P.S. `EET` is my local time zone

Comment: I'm sorry, what is time zone is `AM` exactly? Regardless, you can use the  `pytz` module: http://pytz.sourceforge.net/

Comment: omg! I shouldn't work so much :)) I mean `EET`. Question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the basic approach using the `pytz` module:

```
import datetime
import pytz

fmt = "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"
date = datetime.datetime.strptime("Thu, 23 Jun 2016 07:36:31 GMT", fmt)

gmt_date = pytz.timezone('GMT').localize(date)

print("Time in GMT:", gmt_date.strftime(fmt), sep='\n')

# Now to convert! Notice it took into account "summer time"
print("Time in EET",
      gmt_date.astimezone(pytz.timezone('EET')).strftime(fmt), sep='\n')
```

My output:

```
Time in GMT:
Thu, 23 Jun 2016 07:36:31 GMT
Time in EET
Thu, 23 Jun 2016 10:36:31 EEST
```

Please read the docs, as working with timezones is tricky, and there are many caveats:

http://pytz.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK AM isn't a timezone. Did you try to get `datetime.astimezone(tz)`to work? https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare date-time values, it is much better to convert them both to `datetime` objects, e.g. call `datetime.strptime` on both of the input strings, each with the appropriate format string, and then compare the resulting `datetime` objects.